# Laravel one to many relationship issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i working on laravel v5.8 projec. i have some issue at make one to many relationship.

i have two table one is user which is provide some service and other table services. i want to make one to many relation between them. 
for user must have many services.
for service must belong To on user.
my code :

User.php

```
public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
```

Service.php

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Controller.php

```
 public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('vendor.services',['services'=>Service::with("user")->get()]);
    }
```

blade file

```
 @foreach ($services as $service )
    <tr>
      <td>{{$service->name}}</td>
      <td>{{$service->user_id->name}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

migrations
1.Users

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

2.services

```
Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string("short_desc", 250);
            $table->string("long_desc", 1500);
            $table->double("price", 10);
            $table->bigInteger('type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');
            $table->string("img");
            $table->bigInteger("city_id")->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
            $table->bigInteger("region_id")->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('region_id')->references('id')->on('regions');
            $table->bigInteger("user_id")->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

error:
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /home/nazeeh/Desktop/petVet/resources/views/vendor/services.blade.php)

Comment: *"i have some issue"* - So what *exactly* is the issue? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, but i fixed it by follow the below answer. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

`{{$service->user_id[0]??'not'}}`

with

`{{$service->user ? $service->user->name : 'not'}}`

You can show any field from the `users` table instead of `name`,

like `$service->user->id` or `$service->user->email` etc.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. You can accept and upvote the answer ;)